# Looking for SQL query to display data from 2 tables that is not commone between the tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables that have the exact same structure.

Table MasterList
Acct_id(9)
Name (25)
Address (35)
City(15)
State(2)
ZipCode(5)

and

Table NewMasterList
Acct_id(9)
Name (25)
Address (35)
City(15)
State(2)
ZipCode(5)

I need a query that will display the Acct_ID and Name for all records from each table that are NOT in BOTH tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume the following query should help-

```
select Acct_id,Name 
from MasterList 
where Acct_id not in (select distinct Acct_id from NewMasterList) 

union 

select Acct_id,Name 
from NewMasterList 
where Acct_id not in (select distinct Acct_id from MasterList)
```

cheers

Comment: Although both answers presented returned the same and correct results, I selected this one as it is a bit easier to understand, at least at my level for now.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `acct_ID` is the primary key:

```
SELECT COALESCE(ml.acct_ID, nml.acct_ID) AS AccountID
     , COALESCE(ml.name, nml.name) AS Name 
FROM MasterList ml
    FULL OUTER JOIN NewMasterList nml ON nml.Acct_ID=ml.Acct_ID
WHERE nml.acct_ID IS NULL OR ml.acct_ID IS NULL
```

Comment: This query worked as well as the second query presented.  Each returned the correct data, although the second one using the union with the nested selects was a bit easier to understand at my level.

Comment: This one _should_ be a lot faster, but that probably doesn't matter: this is the kind of thing you do once for analysis.